Proof of a "Fermat Last Theorem" subcase
Let us consider the equation $x^p + y^p -z^p = 0$, where $p$ is some prime number and $x,y,z$ are positive, pairwise coprime, integers.
By Fermat's Little Theorem, we have that $$x^p \equiv x \space (\mod p)$$ $$y^p \equiv y \space (\mod p)$$ $$z^p \equiv z \space (\mod p)$$ where $p$ is some prime number. Therefore, if $x^p + y^p -z^p =0$, then $p \mid x+y-z$, where $\mid$ means "divides". This implies that $p^p \mid (x+y-z)^p$.
If we expand $(x+y-z)^p$ for $p$ being some odd prime number, we get the expression $x^p+y^p-z^p + P(x,y,z,p)$, where $P(x,y,z,p)$ is composed of $\frac{(p+1)(p+2)}{2} - 3$ terms, each of which has a binomial coefficient divisible by $p$, but not by higher powers of $p$. As $p^p \mid x^p+y^p-z^p$, $p^p$ must divide also $P(x,y,z,p)$.
I want to prove the particular case when $p$ divides one of $x,y,z$ (it can divide only one, as they are pairwise coprime), showing that we reach a contradiction ($p^p$ can not divide $P(x,y,z,p))$. ¿Is that feasible? ¿Has it been done?
I see that there are two terms of each expansion (the ones in which one of the variables is powered to $p-1$) that are divisible by $p^p$ and the rest are not, but I don`t know how to deal with this "rest" of terms in a generalized way for every $p$.
I would appreciate any reference or idea on a general strategy for this approach. Thanks for your time!

I doubt this can easily be done. Sophie Germain proved an important result long before this conjecture was solved which , if I remember right , is very similar to what you want to prove. But the proof did not cover all primes.

$p \nmid xyz$ and $p \mid xyz$ are called 1st and 2nd case of FLT respectively. It's generally believed that 2nd case (the one you consider) is harder. For example, 1st case was proven for $p < 100$ (using Sophie Germain's theorem) before 2nd was proven even for $p = 5$.

Thanks for your comments! It seems a difficult task then
